# org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs: [ERROR] in WSO2 EI Project using jenkins

Tags: jenkins, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am building WSO2 Project using jenkins, i have faced some issue while building.can someone please help to sort out this issue? 
**Exception:**

**ERROR: Failed to parse POMs org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs: [ERROR] 'modules.module[2]' specifies duplicate child module VBReadFromEmailBody-ESB @ line 14, column 13** at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:383) at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.buildProjects(MavenEmbedder.java:370) at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.readProjects(MavenEmbedder.java:340) at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.invoke(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1329) at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.invoke(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1126) at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1075) at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1058) at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.parsePoms(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:987) at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:691) at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504) at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1853) at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543) at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97) at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:427)

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.qrsolutions.in</groupId>
  <artifactId>VBReadFromEmailBody</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>VBReadFromEmailBody</name>
  <description>VBReadFromEmailBody</description>
  <modules>
    <module>VBReadFromEmailBody-ESB</module>
    <module>VBReadFromEmailBody-ParseEmailBody</module>
    <module>VBReadFromEmailBody-ESB</module>
    <module>VBReadFromEmailBody-CAR</module>
  </modules>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
          <buildcommands />
          <projectnatures>
            <projectnature>org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.mavenmultimodule.project.nature</projectnature>
          </projectnatures>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

**Note:** i am using jar instead of dependency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have duplicated modules in the pom

```
<modules>
    <module>VBReadFromEmailBody-ESB</module>
    <module>VBReadFromEmailBody-ParseEmailBody</module>
    <module>VBReadFromEmailBody-ESB</module>
    <module>VBReadFromEmailBody-CAR</module>
</modules>
```

Please remove one `<module>VBReadFromEmailBody-ESB</module>` and try again

Comment: Hi @Lahiru Madushanka,
Thanks for your reply. My Project contains only one ESB module,don't know how 2 modules are created in pom.xml, anyway I'll check and let you know.